# Do files disappear from tmpfs when creating process dies?

Tags: linux, tmpfs

I had a discussion with a colleague about tmpfs: we couldn't agree whether tmpfs files survive the death of the process that created them or not. I argued for yes, but wasn't sure. I know that tmpfs is 'just another file system' but it being memory-only, I wasn't sure about the guarantees. Could someone shed some light on the issue?

Comment: When you think about the fact that programs like `mv` and `cp` are processes as well, the behaviour should be obvious. It's also trivial to test with e.g. a minimal python script; in fact testing it would have probably been quicker than writing this question...

Answer (score 2):

Files don't disappear from tmpfs until they are removed or until it is unmounted.

If you want your temporary files to disappear when your process dies, the idiom is to `unlink` them straight after opening them.

Comment: Or of course use `tmpfile` which probably does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It just exists in memory. Switch the computer off and it is gone.

But the files to tmpfs is not linked to a particular process.